# How to Find the smallest integer with exactly N odd divisors.

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, divisor-sum

Hi All I was trying one problem in which is it asking for the smallest number having N odd divisors. As I know the smallest number having n divisors can be find easily.First we need to find the prime factor of the given number for example take $12$. we can write 12 as a product of integers There are only four ways: $12 = 12 = 2 \times 6 = 3 \times 4 = 2 \times 2 \times 3$ and answer is answer is $5^1 \times 3^1 \times 2^2 = 60$. So $60$ is the smallest number with $12$ divisors.

But Here I am stuck how to find smallest number having all odd divisors.

Thanks.

Comment: Your method unfortunately doesn't work all the time. Knowing the prime factorization isn't enough, in a lot of cases you have to group the primes the right way to get the smallest number. $N=16=2\times2\times2\times2$ leads to $3\times5\times7\times11$. But $16=2\times2\times4$ leads to $3^3\times5\times7$ which is smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Every divisor of an odd number is odd, su just skip the prime factor $2$. That is, if you want to find a number with $N$ odd divisors, where
$$N=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_s$$
and
$$p_1\ge\ldots\ge p_s$$
are prime numbers, not necessarily different, take
$$3^{p_1-1}\cdot 5^{p_2-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot q_s^{p_s-1}$$
where $q_s$ is the $s$-th odd prime number.

For your example ($N=12$). Since $N=3\cdot2\cdot 2$, the number you re looking for is $3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7=315$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking same way but I am getting wrong answer for for a given input. This is the problem I am trying http://www.spoj.com/problems/DIVISER9/  for (N = 1024) answer should be 100280245065 but on problem it is not.